# Copying a row screws up pandas column data types, how to avoid?

Tags: python, types, pandas

If after generating a Pandas data frame with some boolean columns, I get the appropriate data types for columns.

```
>>> individuals = pandas.DataFrame([[True, 1],[False, 1]],
...   columns = ["female","fitness"])
... 
>>> print(individuals["female"])
0     True
1    False
Name: female, dtype: bool
```

When I however add another row by copying an already existing row, this breaks:

```
>>> individuals.loc[2] = individuals.loc[1]
>>> print(individuals["female"])
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: female, dtype: object
```

For my `"fitness"` column, I instead get a switch from `int64` to `float64`, which is not optimal either (but slightly better, because at least `float64`s are still a numerical data type, which is what my subsequent code stumbled over). Is there an easy way to avoid this, eg. by using a different method to copy the row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.append`. The `.loc` syntax for extending on purpose will not preserve the dtypes in a multi-dtype case. This will be fixed for 0.15.0

```
In [18]: individuals.append(individuals.loc[1])
Out[18]: 
  female  fitness
0   True        1
1  False        1
1  False        1

In [19]: individuals.append(individuals.loc[1]).dtypes
Out[19]: 
female      bool
fitness    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is a pseudo-bug in that it was never implemented (will be in 0.15.0 though)